# setting proxy in QTP SystemUtil.Run command

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, hp-alm

using the following QTP command to launch google.com page but I want to pass this request through the proxy as all the external links needs to go through proxy 
 due to corporate policies.

> SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program
>   Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "google.com"

What is the best way to set proxy
is it possible to set proxy with scripts?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings) you can send the **proxy-server** to chrome on the command line

> SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "--proxy-server=YOUR_PROXY google.com"